# Nexus 7 wont appear on my PC in the bootloader, semi bricked

Tags: rooting, bootloader

So I tried to root my nexus 7. I realized I done screwed up. However, when I looked for my SuperSU installed file in TWRP, I forgot to install it before hand, when I was at my bootloader, or before that. Now my Nexus 7 will not appear on my P.C to save my life. I have tried it one 2 different cables and PCs. It won't appear as a media device no matter what I try. I also cant open up the OS for some reason. I followed [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2380913) and that did solve my issue of having TWRP. Say I have 0mb internal storage, but I still cant install super SU, or boot up my OS. Whenever I try and start it now I get a slightly lit black screen forever.

EDIT: despite all this I am able to do commands like flashing 
EDIT JUST A FEW MINUTES LATER: removing TWRP via fastboot erase or something, then reinstalling allowed me to see my nexus on my computer, install super SU, and reboot... into a still black screen. i guess ill try and reinstall the system os rom?
EDIT: A few hours ago I reinstalled and flashed the System.img Straight from motorolas website. It worked. Thanks if you helped.

TL/DR:
Device won't show up on my PC. Device is semi bricked in bootloader.

Comment: Consider posting the edited (solution) part as the answer so that you can accept it and indicate that this question is already answered. [Self-answering](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you ever tried using Wugfresh? Try it, they have everything explained in their software, how to install/remove drivers, easy root, bootloader unlock, and many other tools.

Comment: A link to the software would be useful, as well as a bit more information on how it applies specifically to this situation.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475 - Here it is.